# \multirow cell is not vertically centered when \cellspacetoplimit and \cellspacebottomlimit are used

Tags: tables, spacing, vertical-alignment, multirow

Common cell is not centered vertically. [image]

Without `\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}` and `\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}`, it is centered.

[image]

But I do want additional spacing between rows. I can adjust it manually by writing `\multirow{2}{*}[-2pt]{...}` and then trying different fixup parameters. How can I do it without hard-coding the fixup parameter?

```
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}

...

\begin{tabular}{Sl Sl} \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Common cell}
                                  & first cell \\ \cline{2-2}
                                  & second cell\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest another approach: using booktabs, you get horizontal rules which have some vertical padding (`\aboverulesep` and `\belowrulesep`), which results in more or less the same layout as `cellspace`, and variable line widths. There is also the need for a correction, but is intrinsic (`-\aboverulesep`), and it may be incorporated in a user command. Of course, it may vary for multirows of more than 2 rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cellspace, multirow, booktabs}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{Sl Sl} \hline
\multirow{2}{*}[-0.3ex]{Common cell}
                                  & first cell \\ \cline{2-2}
                                  & second cell\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\vskip1cm
\begin{tabular}{ll} \toprule
\multirow{2}{*}[-\aboverulesep]{Common cell}
                                  & first cell \\
                                  \cmidrule{2-2}
                                  & second cell\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What do I write for multirows of more than 2 rows?

Comment: I guess you would have to add a correction of $-n$\aboverulesep for $n$ rows. I might be automated in a command, but it's  more complex than one might think: should work for  one-line rows. For rows with more than one line (typically `p{some length}` or `X` columns) , you'd have to count the total number of *lines*, not the number of rows, and use the number of *rows* for the correction, more precisely the number of *rules* .

Comment: Still don't understand. What if I have 5 rows, for example?

Comment: Ther will be some manual adjustment because of the parameters that come into action. Basically you count the total number of lines in the five rows to a rough estimate, then adjust  to take into account `\aboverulesep`, thickness of horizontal rules, and things like that. It would be easier to explain what to do if you posted a minimal example.